# How can I use one mouse with two computers via Logitech's Unifying receiver and easy-switch technology?

Tags: logitech-unifying

The MX line of Logitech's products has buttons that should in theory allow for fast switching between devices. I have the MX Vertical mouse. One device is my Ubuntu (18.04)'s laptop, one is the Raspberry Pi 400. A Unifying receiver is pluged into each and I installed Solaar on each. Does anybody know how this is supposed to work? How do I pair the mouse with both receivers so taht I can easily switch between them? I cannot make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, never mind. One has to pair the peripherals with the receivers, but each receiver to different channel on the mouse. There are three channels, 1, 2 and 3 and oine can switch between them using the button at the bottom of the mouse. Receiver on my ubuntu needs to be paired with channel and receiver on the Pi needs to be paired with channel number two on the mouse - and then it works. Silly me.